# Issues in Visual C# 2005 finding and selecting a Row in Dataview to be highlight

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, visual-studio-2005, dataview

I have a data table filled with various rows, each has several columns(ie ID, name, Description..)

I am trying to implement a search button where a user chooses a column via a combo box, such as ID or name, and types their requested search in a text box, after clicking the search button I would like to have the row they are looking for selected and highlighted on screen WITHOUT resorting the table as a key is keeping everything in the order in which the table initially populates. another note is that I want all items still visible so I am not going to use .rowfilter as that is already implemented in seperate button.
   I have figured out how to locate the row via it's index and have updated the code accordingly. just wondering how I'd center screen on the said row and highlight it w/o mixing up the order of table

here's what I have so far:

```
private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = textSearch.Text;
    int intquery = Int32.Parse(query);
    DataTable dt = GetAlarmTable();
    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
    DataRow[] foundRows;
    switch (comboboxSearch.Text)
    {
         case "ID":
         {

              dv.Sort = "ID"; 
              index = dv.Find(intquery);
              foundRows = dt.Select("ID = '" + intquery + "'");
              break;
          } 
    }
//??? ???

}
```

If you have code to share, Ideas, or links please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the function I typically use.  Make sure you have the `SelectionMode` property on the `DataGridView` set to `FullRowSelect`.

```
public static void EnsureGridRowIsSelectedAndVisible(DataGridViewRow row)
{
    if (row == null)
        return;

    row.Selected = true;

    // Center the item in the display
    row.DataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 

        Math.Max(row.Index - Convert.ToInt32(row.DataGridView.DisplayedRowCount(false) / 2), 0);
}
```